# How to make a plugin option panel WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins

I am going to make a WordPress plugin to change the Login Logo. But Now I am trying to make a option panel and how user can edit the plugin function admin panel.

```
//Function For Login Logo Change
function awesome_custom_login_logo() {
    echo '<style type="text/css">
         h1 a { background-image:url(/images/logo.jpg) !important; }
        </style>';
}
add_action('login_head', 'awesome_custom_login_logo');

//Function For Login Logo Url
function awesome_login_logo_url() {
    return get_bloginfo( 'url' );
}
add_filter( 'login_headerurl', 'awesome_login_logo_url' );

//Function For Login Logo Title
function awesome_login_logo_url_title() {
    return 'Your Site Name and Info';
}
add_filter( 'login_headertitle', 'awesome_login_logo_url_title' );
```

Any Idea about create a menu, submenu, option page etc ?

Answer (score 0):

You can take refrence from wordpress function admin_menu and add_sub_menu_page